# Room very slow read operation

Tags: android, performance, android-room

I have a room database and I'm trying to read data from it, when reading 16k records, the operation takes 15seconds.
this is my code

```
@Entity(tableName = "reading_table")
data class DatabaseReading(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val readingId: Int = 0,
    val readingNum: Int,
    val deviceId: String,
    val readingTime: Long,
    val topRh: Double,
    val topTemp: Double,
    val botRh: Double,
    val botTemp: Double,
)
```

this is my DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM reading_table WHERE deviceId = :id ORDER BY readingTime ASC")
    suspend fun getDeviceReadings(id: String): List<DatabaseReading>
```

then from my viewmodel I'm running the query

```
    fun getReadings() {
        Timber.d("get readings start")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val time = measureTimeMillis {
                    devicesRepository.database.deviceDatabaseDao.getDeviceReadings(
                        deviceID
                    )
                }
                Timber.d("get readings time $time")
            }
        }
    }
```

getReadings is taking 15563ms for 16155 records.

how can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out that the issue was caused by the database inspector plugin on android studio.
as long as I don't use it everything runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I mean for a mobile device that's a pretty sizable amount of records, chances are you dont need and probably wont use all 16k of them.

You should probably use the [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library for room to only load chunks of data instead of everything

Comment: I need to plot a graph from the data so I do need to load everything, I found this article and they are running tests for 50K rows and the values are way less. https://medium.com/swlh/android-dbms-performance-comparison-using-the-jetpack-benchmark-library-19581bf67443 one other strange thing is that inserting the same amount of data takes 1900ms

Comment: I cant see the article since its behind a paywall